# Change encoding in OpenOffice Writer

Tags: encoding, openoffice-writer

I have a .doc file that was created with Word 97 and it's text is mostly in Greek. I am trying to open it with OpenOffice Writer.

In Word 97 the document is fine but when I open it with OpenOffice the greek letters are "rubbish" characters while the english letters are displayed fine. Thus I believe it is an encoding problem. I have searched a lot but I wasn't able to find if it's possible to change the encoding in OpenOffice.

Does anyone know if it's possible to change a document's encoding in OpenOffice and how to do it?

Comment: I already have tried changing the fonts without success

Comment: Better post online an example document for us to give a try. Do you have access to a newer Office version which could convert it to a newer format.

Comment: ok. I will post an example. yes i do have access but i prefer word 97 because it is significantly lighter

Comment: Are fonts installed for all users? In Linux, a font used by Word might not be visible to another application.

Comment: yes the fonts is the same